# When I print an email the images are pixelated

Tags: email, images, printing

When I print an email with a picture in it, the image is always pixelated. The image (logo) I've made is 300DPI, so there shouldn't be a problem? Anyone got a solution?

Comment: What is the resolution of the image? As in: what is the width and height of the image in pixels?

Comment: @BartArondson 492px width 66px height

Comment: At 300dpi, if the printed image is much larger than 2-3 inchs across, it'll be pixelated.